# SolR 6.6.0 : Error 500 when requesting more than 4 facet

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I have a 500 error in solR with this query :

```
q=*&wt=json&rows=0&fq=date:[2014-01-01T09:15:57.000Z/SECOND TO *]&facet=true&facet.field=text&facet.limit=5
```

I noticed that if put the parameter "facet.limit" to less than 5 it works but otherwise it does not. Here is the stack from SolR :

```
msg : "Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/core_replica1: Exception during facet.field: text" 
trace : "org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: 
Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/core_replica1: Exception during facet.field: text\n\tat
```

Do you know why this kind of error would happen?

I use Solr 6.6.0.
The field that I request is a org.apache.solr.schema.TextField that is :

Indexed | Tokenized | Stored    | TermVector Stored | Store Offset With TermVector  | Store Position With TermVector for the properties and shema

Thanks!

EDIT : solr logs :

```
 2018-03-29 15:26:24.137 INFO  (qtp42121758-601) [c:core s:shard2     r:core_node1 x:core_shard2_replica1] o.a.s.c.S.Request [core_shard2_replica1]  
 webapp=/solr path=/select params={facet.field={!terms%3D$text__terms}text&distrib=false&qt=weblab_facet&fl=id,score&shards.purpose=32&text__terms=est&fq=date:    

 [2014-01-01T09:15:57.000Z/SECOND+TO+*]&shard.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/core_shard2_replica1/&rows=0&version=2&f.mainDate.facet.range.end=NOW/DAY&q=*&facet.limit=5&f.mainDate.facet.range.gap=%2B1DAY&
 NOW=1522329984131&isShard=true&facet=true&f.mainDate.facet.range.start=NOW/DAY-5DAYS&wt=javabin&facet.sort=count} hits=5 status=500 QTime=0

  2018-03-29 15:26:24.137 ERROR (qtp42121758-601) [c:core s:shard2 r:core_node1 x:core_shard2_replica1] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception during facet.field: text
at org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets.lambda$getFacetFieldCounts$0(SimpleFacets.java:809)
```

And :

```
 2018-03-29 15:26:24.137 ERROR (qtp42121758-601) [c:core s:shard2 r:core_node1 x:core_shard2_replica1]
  o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase 

 org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception during facet.field: text
at org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets.lambda$getFacetFieldCounts$0(SimpleFacets.java:809)

 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.rewrite(IndexSearcher.java:683)
```

Comment: What does the actual Solr log say?

Comment: Added some SolR Log